# Sending data between classes in Cocoa Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, class

I've started programming for iPhones about a month ago now, and have found the site very useful. So I though someone out there could help me.

I think I understand the basics of how @property and @synthesise work and using setters and getters, but I have a problem.

Say I have 3 classes: Functions, Class1 and Class2.

Functions is a class that holds all the data and Class1 and Class2 reads that data from it and writes new data (amends the data) to it. However both Class1 and Class2 will make there own instance of Functions as it is basically just a blueprint for the data.

So if Class1 writes or 'sets' some data (lets say) 5 to Functions and Class2 'gets' it, Class2 will get back 0 as Class1 only wrote 5 to its instance of Functions, that Class2 can't see.

I suppose first off, is that right? Second, how do I do it so Class1 and Class2 can see the same data to get and set.

Thanks for the help. I realise this might include a topic I haven't learned yet, but if so I'd love to know what it is, so I can lern it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a number of options that all stem back to ensuring Class1 and Class2 use the same instance of the "shared object".

1. Expressly pass the same instance to Class1 and Class2 from the outside, rather than allowing Class1 and Class2 to create an instance themselves; or
2. Provide a singleton initializer to the Functions class, then make sure Class1 and Class2 use this; or
3. Use a design pattern known as the registry pattern, and ensure Class1 and Class2 get their instance of the functions class from the registry; or
4. Use dependency injection (complex).

Scenario (1) is the simplest to comprehend since it goes exactly like this:

```
Functions *funcs = [[Functions alloc] init];

Class1 *obj1 = [[Class1 alloc] initWithFunctions:funcs];
Class2 *obj2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithFunctions:funcs];
/* or alternatively use setters after initialization */
```

Scenario (2) is the next simplest and is very common.  Cocoa provides singleton initializers to many of it's classes.  Whenever you see `+shared...` as a prefix for an initializer it's probably returning a singleton.

```
@implementation Functions

+(id)sharedFunctions {
  static Functions *sharedFunctions = nil;

  @synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedFunctions == nil) {
      sharedFunctions = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedFunctions;
  }
}

@end
```

The static variable is initialized only once, which means you can lazily load an instance of the object into it using a check for it's initial value (which only occurs once).  Every subsequent call to the method returns the same instance.

```
Functions *f1 = [Functions sharedFunctions];
Functions *f2 = [Functions sharedFunctions];

/* f1 == f2; */ // always
```

Option (3) isn't seen very much in objective-C compared to in other languages and it achieves much the same goals as the singleton.  The idea is that you have a dictionary of objects that can be looked up by key.  Everything that needs access to items in the registry just asks the registry for its own instance.  Typically the registry itself would be a singleton.

Option (4), dependency injection, is actually a very elegant solution with a number of benefits at the cost of additional complexity.  The benefits come from the fact that you've ensured the dependencies are always loosely coupled (which makes swapping out implementations, and unit testing the dependencies independently much simpler).  The complexity comes from the non-standard mechanisms for retrieving instances of what you need.

Dependency injection revolves around the idea that no object instantiates its own dependencies.  Instead of relies on something else to provide those dependencies.  That "something else" being known as a dependency-injection container.  A dependency injection container is effectively a layer on top of the registry pattern, since the container will either hold pre-built instances of the dependencies, or it will know how to instantiate new instances.

In the simplest case, dependency injection is exactly what I demonstrated in option (1).  You don't even need a dependency-injection container to achieve this.

Shifting up a level of complexity, dependency injection brings in the concept of a DI container, which encapsulates a number of existing design patterns (the registry, as seen in option (3), the singleton (likely, but not strictly) and the factory (to know how to make new instances of objects it manages).

Demonstrating a full-implementation of a DI container would probably be beyond the scope of this question, but from a public interface point of view, one implementation might look like this:

```
DIContainer *container = [DIContainer sharedContainer];

[container registerClass:[ClassA class]];
[container registerClass:[ClassB class]];
[container registerDependentProperty:@selector(setClassA:)
                      withInstanceOf:[ClassA class]
                            forClass:[ClassB class]];

ClassB *obj = [container makeInstanceOfClass:[ClassB class]];
NSLog(@"ClassB's -classA type = %@", [[obj classA] class]);
```

I just typed that off the top of my head in the middle of this post, so don't assume it is 100% accurate, but you get the concept.  The container has been instructed that when it initializes instances of ClassB, it must then invoke `-setClassA:`, using an instance of `ClassA`, which it also initializes according to the rules defined in the container (in this case there are no dependencies of `ClassA` so it just returns a plain instance.

If you take nothing more away from this answer, just remember options (1) and (2) ;)

Comment: Cheers man, thats really useful. I've gone for option 2 and it works well. Option 3 and 4 went over my head a little, but I'll re-read them tomorrow after I've had a bit of sleep. Might make some more sense in the morning. Thanks for the help though, very useful. :-D

Comment: No problem, I think your choice to go with option (2) is a good one.  Option (1) is "technically" the best as the singleton has somewhat of a bad reputation among many developers, due to the difficulty with which it can be tested (unclean test environment).  However, used correctly it's perfectly fine.  Actually, since Objective-C does not have a single exclusive initializer/constructor like other languages, the singleton is not 100% forced, so it can be worked around in testing in any case.  Option 3 is quite simple, but yes, option (4) is a subject that confuses even experienced developers.

Comment: I know this question is old, but this totally helped me. +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide. The section relevant to your question is called [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is really more a question about object oriented programming in general, but the solution applies to Objective-C as well.  What you want to do is create one instance of Functions.  That instance should be shared between the instances of Class1 and Class2.

```
Functions *f = [[Functions alloc] init];
Class1 *c1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
Class2 *c2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];
// set the value of a instance variable of f to the value of aValue from c1
[f setSomeValue:[c1 aValue]];
// now change it to c2's aValue
[f setSomeValue:[c2 aValue]];
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I'm guessing you'd only put the bits with Class1 in it in the Class1 file and only put the bits with Class2 in it in the Class2 file. Though init the Functions instance goes in both?

Sorry if Im repeating things, but I've been going over and over this stuff and my mind has got a bit boggled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of on-line references out there but I found this book to be a great asset. Programming in Objective-C 2.0 (2nd Ed.) by Stephen G. Kochan. It is a great starting place.